# Invalid syntax error in pycrypto while importing paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko, python-3.5, pycrypto

I am getting the following error when I am trying to import paramiko. I am using python3.5 and paramiko 2.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paramiko_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 50, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\paramiko\dsskey.py", line 26, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6.1-py3.5-win32.egg\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py", line 88, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import _DSA, _slowmath, pubkey
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6.1-py3.5-win32.egg\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py", line 53
    if pow(2,159L) < q < pow(2,160L):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Has anyone resolved this?

Comment: Looks like someone tried to build a Python 2-only library for Python 3.  You should report this as a bug in pycrypto.

Comment: Ok. Any suggestions on a temporary solution? I basically want to use Paramiko library.